# JNA vs. DLL (Delphi)

Tags: java, delphi, java-native-interface, jna

I'm a new(bie) here but, I have a "big problem"

I Have a DLL (in Delphi) and I want to access it by Java. It's easy if you use a simple return or procedure in the "body" (.dpr) of DLL. But I need to use a Interface because I want to use a same code in a Desktop Application and a Web Application (using java). Code bellow:

TESTLIB.DLL

```
library TESTLIB;  
{$DEFINE TESTLIB}  

uses  
  System.SysUtils,  
  System.Classes,  
  TestInt in 'TestInt.pas';  

{$R *.res}  

function MyReturn(Test: PTest): PChar; stdcall;  
begin  
    Result := 'Im Here!';  
    Test^.vResult := 'Test 123';  
end;  

exports MyReturn;  

begin  
end.
```

Interface TestInt.pas

```
unit TestInt;  

interface  

type  
  PTest = ^TTest;  
  TTest = record  
    vResult: PChar;  
  end;  

  {$IFNDEF TESTELIB}  
  function MyReturn(Test: PTest): PChar; stdcall;  
  {$ENDIF}  

implementation  

{$IFNDEF TESTELIB}  
function MyReturn; external 'TESTLIB.DLL' name 'MyReturn';  
{$ENDIF}  

end.
```

and how I access this using a simple application in Delphi:

```
unit FormMain;  

interface  

uses  
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,   Vcl.Graphics,  
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;  

type  
  TForm1 = class(TForm)  
    Button1: TButton;  
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);  
  private  
    { Private declarations }  
  public  
    { Public declarations }  
  end;  

var  
  Form1: TForm1;  

implementation  

{$R *.dfm}  

uses TestInt;  //The interface

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);  
var  
  Test: TTest; //Type declared in Interface TestInt.pas  
begin  
    ShowMessage(MyReturn(@Test)); //Returns Im Here!  

    ShowMessage(Test.vResult); //Test 123  
end;  

end.
```

I want to access this using Java (JNI, JNA, etc... would be better if an example can be provided)

thanks a lot guys!

Comment: That's not going to work at all. You are trying to pass a string from the DLL to the caller. The way to do that is to get the caller to allocate the memory and let the DLL populate it. You aren't doing that. Your code will probably work at the moment because you are using a string literal. It's going to crash and burn when you use a string variable. Also, there are no interfaces here. What you call an interface is just a record containing a pointer.

Comment: It's also not clear what you are looking for here. Do you know anything about JNA/JNI? Which one do you want to use? If you know nothing then it's time for you to go away, read up on these technologies, decided which one you want and put together a very basic example using simpler types, e.g. int. As it stands it looks like you want us to 1. Choose between JNA/JNI. 2. Teach you how to use whichever is chosen. 3. Teach you about Delphi DLL interop.   All that is way too broad. Please narrow down the question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, with "interface" he probably means the interface part of a unit in contrast to the "body" of the dpr.

Comment: this interface that causes the main application functions and procedures accessing the DLL. This DLL I use in my Desktop Application, but, I don't want to "reinvent the wheel". If is possible, I need help (yes sir I use JNA but IF EXISTS an other method (JNI) I would to know) else, sorry.

Comment: In your situation JNI will most certainly be more difficult than JNA.  I recommend you take @DavidHeffernan's advice and read up on the difference between the two so you can better refine your questions.

Comment: See also [Is there a tool which creates C header files for Delphi (Win32) DLLs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205636/is-there-a-tool-which-creates-c-header-files-for-delphi-win32-dlls) for a way to generate JNA bindings automatically for Delphi: *Delphi source -> create C header -> convert to Java binding -> use Delphi DLL from Java*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general Delphi DLLs (using stdcall calling convention) are accessed in the same way that you would access Win32 APIs.  You should be able to figure out appropriate type mappings by examining the sizes of the Delphi types and replacing them with similarly-sized Java types.

`PCHAR` maps to a Java String, so your "interface" as provided would look something like this:

```
public interface TestInt extends StdCallLibrary {
    TestInt INSTANCE = (TestInt)Native.loadLibrary("TestInt", TestInt.class);

    class Test extends Structure {
        public String vResult;
        public Test() { }
        public Test(Pointer p) { 
            super(p);
            read();
        }
        protected List getFieldOrder() { return Arrays.asList(new String[] { "vResult" }); }
    }

    String MyReturn(Test test);
}
```

Bear in mind [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan)'s warning about returning strings; if delphi allocates the memory, it must later free the memory, so it's usually easier to have the caller (Java) pass in allocated memory and have delphi simply write to the provided buffer.

Answer (score 2):

> want to use a same code in a Desktop Application and a Web Application
>   (using java)

Instead of using JNI/JNA for this task, your Delphi code could be exposed through a HTTP web service (for example JSON/REST) instead of a direct in-process communication method. For the Delphi-based web service, you could use Indy, Synapse or build a ISAPI DLL for IIS. The Java Web Application then acts as a web service client. And it can run on many operating system, while JNI/JNA required that both parts are compiled and run on the same target.

---

Update: regarding your comment, if speed is very important, there are other options for in-process communication, for example shared memory mapped files, and IOCP, which are very fast.

However I do not think that a socket based solution will be to slow. You can create a direct socket connection between a Delphi app and the Java process and transfer thousands of messages per second easily. Are you sure that there will be a problem if messages are not processed within less than a millisecond?

The [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html) suggests to use pipes and sockets for inter-process communication:

> To facilitate communication between processes, most operating systems
>   support Inter Process Communication (IPC) resources, such as pipes and
>   sockets. IPC is used not just for communication between processes on
>   the same system, but processes on different systems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer brother, but, I have this DLL and my application will access it and "validate" some informations and needs to be "faster" (it will runs in Server).

Comment: Thanks a lot bro! I'll use another "way" to do that. The idea (sockets) are very suggestive. Thanks for all!

Comment: JNA is not exactly difficult. In fact it's really easy.

Comment: Given that the OP expressed a preference for writing in Java, and that the DLL does not already provide an IPC endpoint, you've just added to the list of requirements ahead of a working solution.